# Import Face Recognition data into Apple Photos

Tags: photos, exif, face-recognition, xmp

I want to import my photo collection from Picasa into Apple Photos. Folders, Tags and Location works fine. The only missing feature is the import of face recognition data. I've spent days to tag the faces in Picasa, so I definitively want to keep this information.

I've included the face recognition data into the pictures itself, both by the Preferences checkbox "Store name tags in photo" and by Tools -> Experimental -> Write faces to XMP.

Importing the data into DigiKam works, so I know it's there. Does anybody have a clue on how to import face recognition data into Apple Photos?